# Constrain function generic parameter to associated type

Tags: swift, generics, xcode7.3

Why does this fail with the following: `Inheritance from non-protocol, non-class type` on the function declaration line?

```
protocol Foo {
    associatedtype AType
}

struct Container<F: Foo> {

    let foo: F

    func doWork<S: F.AType>(s: S) { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that the following compiles:

```
protocol Foo {
    associatedtype A
}

struct Container<F: Foo> {

    func f(a: F.A) { }
}
```

However, in the case of:

```
struct Container<F: Foo> {

    func f<A : F.A>(a: A) { } // error: inheritance from non-protocol, non-class type
}
```

... the type `F.A` is completely unconstrained, so it may well be, say, an `Int`, which you cannot inherit from or conform to using the `:` syntax.

If you really need a more generic solution than `(a: F.A)` then something along these lines might do it:

```
protocol Bar { }

protocol Foo {
    associatedtype A : Bar
}

struct Container<F: Foo> {

    func f<A : Bar>(a: A) { }
}
```

You can now express any expectations about `a` parameter using `Bar` protocol.

Better still, you might be able to implement the method as an extension of `Foo`:

```
protocol Foo {
    associatedtype A

    func f(_: A) // if you want this to be a requirement
}

extension Foo /* where A is constrained so you can do something with it */ {

    func f(a: A) { }
}
```

Comment: In my use case, the `Container` method `f` must be constrained to be a subclass of `Foo`'s type. That is, it must either be type `Foo.A` or a subclass. I'm not sure you're right when you say that F.A being unconstrained is the problem. After all if we make `associatedtype A : Bar`, `func f<A : F.A>(a: A) { }` still fails.

Comment: I never suggested `associatedtype A : Bar`, `func f<A : F.A>(a: A) { }` – which must indeed fail. Please have a look more carefully at the `Bar` snippet... Note also that you can replace `Bar` with a specific class if that is what you need. As for "not being sure", do you have any particular objections to my explanation (for example in case of `F.A` being an `Int`)?

Comment: I did notice the difference between our snippets. I was responding to where you cite `the type F.A is completely unconstrained` as a reason for the error. Even with constraints, the outcome is the same. Why can an associated type not be used as a constraint?

Comment: `F.A` **is** the associated type **and** it is completely unconstrained in the sense that it can be anything at all in your code example. This means that when you write `A : F.A` you are asking the compiler to guarantee that `A` will be either inheriting or conforming to `F.A`, whatever it may be (that's what `:` means). But compiler cannot guarantee that since `F.A` can be, for example, a `final` class or a struct since your `Foo` protocol insists it can be anything at all.

Comment: Constraining the method parameter in one of the suggested ways to a class or a protocol (i.e. anything that you can inherit from or conform to using `:`) will solve the problem.